# How to bring back folder privileges, that I revoked in registry with regedit?

Tags: windows-registry, privileges, regedit

I revoked read and write privileges for my user (but not for admin) in my registry for a folder. I tried to open the folder and it said, that I don't have these priveleges. Ерут I opened regedit.exe as admin user -- and to no avail. Now I cannot get access to this folder them back. What do I do?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Can you please edit your question to tell us what you've tried on your own to solve this problem?

Comment: thank you, @Twisty, i tried to elaborate my question. is it better now?

Comment: When you say *folder* are you referring to a **registry key** or an actual **file folder** within the file system? Have you tried taking ownership of the registry key if that's what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running regedit as an administrator browse to the key you can not open.
Right click it, Permissions. Click advanced.
Click 'Change' next to owner. Search your username or administrators and click check name, or click advanced and find a correct user or group.
Click ok. Then click apply in the advanced security settings screen.
Now that you have taken over the ownership of the key you should be able to modify the permissions.

Comment: this is exactly what i described i did: i opened regedit with admin rights (via right-click menu) and tried to edit folder preferences, but tells me that I still have no rights

Comment: Make sure you claim ownership first, [here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/) is a guide with images. if that still does not work, you could try repeating it while running regedit with under the SYSTEM account. You can either use this [tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/runassystem/)  in order to do so or use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) (command line (running as admin)= psexec-i -s regedit.exe)

Comment: I was finally able to do that only after I rebooted. Thank you.